# How do I take input from a user, store it in an empty variable and print the variable?

Tags: python, variables

Here is my code:

```
name = ' '

Nameval = name("Enter the victims IP address: ")

print("Hello, " + name)
```

I want this code to take the input from Nameval, store it in the "name" variable and then print the name variable. However, it wont work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`input([prompt])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

```
name = input("Enter the victims IP address: ")

print("Hello, " + name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong. You are not asking for an input, try this.

```
name = input('Enter IP address: ')
print(f'Hello {name}')
```

F string are better than concatination